# Could someone help me with my issue?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, help

I had the following issue when connecting to Tor. If I tried using a VPN such as hotspot shield would that fix my issue? Any help would be great!

`10/6/2016 0:15:33 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/6/2016 0:15:33 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/6/2016 0:15:33 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/6/2016 0:15:33 AM.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
10/6/2016 0:15:34 AM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
10/6/2016 0:35:17 AM.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host 1DBAED235E3957DE1ABD25B4206BE71406FB61F8 at 46.101.151.222:443) 
10/6/2016 0:35:17 AM.300 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
10/6/2016 0:35:17 AM.300 [WARN]  9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
10/6/2016 0:35:22 AM.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
10/6/2016 0:35:22 AM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/6/2016 0:35:22 AM.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
10/6/2016 0:35:22 AM.100 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.`

Answer (score 1):

A VPN would help, but a better solution would be to use bridges. Something is blocking Tor from connecting to the directory server.

Just follow the steps on the bridges website: https://bridges.torproject.org/